# Custom Module is not appearing in Admin Panel in Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2.0

I am following this article(https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/) and creating a custom module in Magento 2.2.0 but when i reach the step where i have to check my custom module in admin panel

Store >> Advanced >> Advanced i don't see anything there.

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Connextar_CXMageMods" setup_version="2.0.1" />
</config>
```

Registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Iftikhar uddin
 * Date: 10/22/2017
 * Time: 8:54 AM
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Connextar_CXMageMods',
    __DIR__
);
```

Code Directory Stucture is \app\code\Connextar\CXMageMods\

Comment: Paste your `system.xml` file content please

Comment: @AlexDinca where that is located?  What do you mean by system.xml do you mean module.xsd?

Comment: my bad, sorry. I thought you were adding a section in the the store configuration area.

Comment: @keyurshah Why you flag it duplicate? Can you elaborate? The question you answered is about disabling a module and mine question is completely different!

Comment: Please read the blog first. in blog you can clearly see that they have mentioned that after enabling the module you can see your module  `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced` that the module is present. But this section is completely removed from `magento2.2` :) @lftikhar

Comment: @KeyurShah so where i can see that my Module is in there in adminpanel. When i check the status it say module is enabled but i can't see it in admin panel!

Comment: You can see check by CMD just execute the command `php bin/magento module:status Connextar_CXMageMods` and there is no option in admin to check until and unless you create some custom configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment in `Magento2.2` `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced` section is completely removed from `magento2.2` so you can not see your module status there. If you want to check you can use cmd panel and excute below command ,

```
php bin/magento module:status Connextar_CXMageMods
```

Where `Connextar` is your module namespace and `CXMageMods` is your module name.

*Note: I am adding the answer because there is some confusion to this user [Iftikhar uddin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/42160/iftikhar-uddin)*